# Counting Unique IDs In a LEFT/RIGHT JOIN Query in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, distinct

I am working on a database to track staff productivity. Two of the ways we do that is by monitoring the number of orders they fulfil and by tracking their error rate.

Each order they finish is recorded in a table. In one day they can complete many orders.
It is also possible for a single order to have multiple errors.

I am trying to create a query that provides a summary of their results. This query should have one column with "TotalOrders" and another with "TotalErrors".

I connect the two tables with a LEFT/RIGHT join since not all orders will have errors.

The problem comes when I want to total the number of orders. If someone made multiple mistakes on an order, that order gets counted multiple times; once for each error.

I want to modify my query so that when counting the number of orders it only counts records with distinct OrderID's; yet, in the same query, also count the total errors without losing any.

Is this possible?

Here is my SQL

```
SELECT Count(tblTickets.TicketID) AS TotalOrders, 
       Count(tblErrors.ErrorID) AS TotalErrors 
FROM tblTickets 
LEFT JOIN tblErrors ON tblTickets.TicketID = tblErrors.TicketID;
```

I have played around with SELECT DISTINCT and UNION but am struggling with the correct syntax in Access. Also, a lot of the examples I have seen are trying to total a single field rather than two fields in different ways.

To be clear when totalling the OrderCount field I want to only count records with DISTINCT TicketID's. When totalling the ErrorCount field I want to count ALL errors.

Ticket = Order.

[Query Result: Order Count Too High](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zK1lF.png)

[Ticket/Order Table: Total of 14 records](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPmk3.png)

[Error Table: You can see two errors for the same order on 8th](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRSMG.png)

Comment: How is the ```LEFT JOIN``` working? In ```tblTickets```, the ```TicketID``` column contains IDs, and in ```tblErrors```, it contains dates? Also, if you would count distinct ```TicketID``` in the first table, you still would get the same result since the values are indeed distinct. What is your desired result for ```TotalOrders```?

Comment: Hi,

Sorry that my question was not entirely clear. The TicketID field in tblErrors is a foreign key. That field uses a lookup to make the result more human-readable. However, it is still an integer value.

Unfortunately, as you can see in the pictures, the current query doesn't work as it counts records it shouldnt.

When an order has multiple errors the order count value of that order is increased.

Eg If someone has 3 errors on an order with ID = 1 Then that order counts as three orders completed by that person (when it should be 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. do a query that counts orders by staff from Orders table and a query that counts errors by staff from Errors table then join those two queries to Staff table (queries can be nested for one long SQL statement)
2. correlated subqueries

```
SELECT Staff.*, 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM Orders WHERE StaffID = Staff.ID) AS CntOrders, 
    (SELECT Count(*) FROM Errors WHERE StaffID = Staff.ID) AS CntErrors
FROM Staff;
```

3. use DCount() domain aggregate function

Option 1 is probably the most efficient and option 3 the least.